# Mandarin Language Translation API for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, machine-translation

I want to implement Mandarin language translation feature in my iPad app, is there any API which is free that I can use, or any other way to do this..

Comment: Any specifications?  Such as if you require offline translation etc.

Comment: Ya am preferring offline translation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only free API is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx

For a long time people used Google, but they cut off free use some time ago.